# Private Route in react-router v6 taking Authentication using redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

[image]

```
import React, { Fragment,useSelector } from 'react'
import {Navigate,Route,Routes} from 'react-router-dom'

const ProtectedR = ({children}) => {
    const  {loading,isAuthenticated}= useSelector(state => state.user)
    
    if(!loading){
    return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to="/login" />
    }
}

export default ProtectedR
```

Comment: What is the issue? What isn't a function? Looks like `useSelector` is being flagged... have you imported it?

Comment: @ashish Import ```useSelector``` from ```react-redux``` not from ```react```

Comment: Ah, yeah, @MuhammadBilalBangash has it.... don't know how I missed that. Yes, import `useSelector` from `react-redux`. Voted to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers and good luck.

Comment: oo thanks everyone  its working

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in [React Router V6](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview).

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Navigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const  { loading, isAuthenticated } = useSelector(state => state.user);
  if(loading){
    return null;
  }
  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to={'/login'} />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I always do and has never failed me.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
const loggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.loggedIn);
return (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) =>
      loggedIn ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/login',
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  ></Route>
 );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Then you just import it and use it like this

```
 <PrivateRoute path='/top/secret' exact component={TopSecretPage} />
```

Comment: This does not work with React Router V6 https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview For future reference with v6 checkout https://github.com/akursat/react-router-example